# Why does William shoot arrows at the axe in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-great-wall

In this scene from *The Great Wall*, William and Tovar are fighting the beasts. Tovar throws his axe in the air, and then William shoots arrows at it.

[image: animated GIF of the scene described above]

Why is William shooting arrows at the axe?

Answer (score 5):

William and Tovar are [battle buddies.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_buddy) They mount an attack together by diversion and attack which is seen multiple times in this film.

First when they are on the wall as prisoner, Tovar uses a flag to invite Taotei to attack him and slides out of way, taking this opportunity William kills it.

Now due to fog hindering visibility Taotei are drawn towards sound.
So they take positions to direct Taoties to sound of arrow hitting axe.

They do it by Tovar tossing the axe, William striking it and then Tovar can hit it in the eye for a kill.

Comment: Why aiming for the eye?

Comment: @DhanrajKumar: In movie it's shown that they are killed by destroying their eyes. Maybe that's their vulnerability because they are hard skinned creature having no effect of arrows. There are three ways they are show to be killed in movie. By hitting hard on eye, cutting them in half and by burning them.

Comment: Ok I now understand eye is the main thing in beast creature to kill it, then how shooting on the axe can help him to aim the eye of the beast?

Comment: @DhanrajKumar: That's what I explained in my answer.